# Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key in ios 9

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios9, xcode7

I have upgrade my xcode to latest version and after updating I tried to submit build to appstore while I am archiving I got the following issue:

```
Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key
```

I have searched my sites and some links but could not find solutions. Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Looking for anyone's help

Answer (score 2):

Disable bitcode and remove that key from Info.plist

In .plist you will find it with **"Executable file"** name.

Comment: I've tried this a bunch of times, but once I remove the entry from the .plist file, i disabled bit code, when I try to validate the archive i get an error: `invalid bundle structure - .../Frameworks/ResearchKit.framework/ResearchKit is not permitted.  App can't contain standalone executables or libraries...`  When i revert back the plist I can validate and upload, but the I get the error about the unexpected executable key... can't win

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `CFBundleExecutable` key from the Info.plist file of the offending bundle. In my case it was ApptentiveResources.bundle that was causing the problem.

The easiest way of doing this is press Cmd-Shift-F in Xcode and search for CFBundleExecutable. In the list of files containing that key you should see the bundle mentioned in the error message. Delete the key from that file (but leave all the other instances in other files).

Then when uploading the archive to the App Store, make sure you uncheck the 'Include bitcode' checkbox, otherwise you will continue getting errors with that bundle.